# Prevent developers from using constants

Tags: c#, coding-style, coding-standards, teamwork

I have one one software system which allows developers to specify an ID or name to create `NodeReferences`. Both work fine, but ID's are not guaranteed to be the same across different environments. I've tried in documentation and in conversations to stress that ID's should not be hard coded (since they will break when deployed to a different environments), but some developers are still using them.

This works only in dev environment:

```
var level = LevelReference.ById(20);
var node = NodeReference.ByName(level, _patientGuid.ToString());
```

This works in all environments:

```
var app = ApplicationReference.ByName("Reporting");
var area = AreaReference.ByName(app, "Default");
var level = LevelReference.ByName(area, "Patient");
var node = NodeReference.ByName(level, _patientGuid.ToString());
```

I think the appeal is just that it produces fewer lines of code. The use of ID's is not by itself bad (since there are valid use cases like caching the ID returned from the server and using it later for faster look-up), but hard-coded ID's are bad. Most of the time the first code will throw an exception, but it's possible that it could be a valid ID for a different object than the developer intended, and this could result in very bad problems.

What's the best way to discourage the use of such constants in code? Ideally I'd like throw some kind of compiler error when I see code like the first example, or at least throw an exception before the call gets down to the database.

Comment: For what it's worth, add a `ByEnum` method and then use that everywhere you need to hard-code the desired value.

Comment: Some people hold the opinion that database row id's should never leave the database since they are essentially an implementation detail. In that school of thought, every [aggregate root] object would be referenced by some unique natural or surrogate key instead. I can see a lot of logic in this mentality although I've never had the scope to try it myself.

Comment: Two words:  "code reviews."

Comment: @MattDavey the names are kind of like a surrogate key. To avoid developers stepping on each other's toes, each name is guaranteed to be unique only within it's parent context. That's precisely why I'd like to limit the use of ID's.

Comment: @Blrfl Yeah, to that point, I totally agree. Time and other resource constraints being what they are, this slipped through the cracks. I should've stressed code reviews much more strongly.

Comment: The kind of expressions you'd be trying to hunt down look like they'd be easy to find with `grep`, so you might be able to get a leg up on your code base that way.

Comment: Any constant passed into `ById(int)` would be a [magic number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad).  Not getting rid of magic numbers is a bigger issue than just passing them into *this* method.

Comment: Not sure grep and code reviews (i.e. static analysis) are good answers to this question. Those both seem like pretty dull (if somewhat applicable) tools for this problem. There *are* language features designed for questions like this.

Comment: @MattDavey: It's a good general approach but valid exceptions do exist. But in those cases, the known IDs should always be configurable (e.g. via the app settings) and the maintenance effort of keeping them up to date is a cost you have to accept.

Comment: It seems you are asking about hardcoded **literals** rather than _constants_. They are related concepts but not the same.

Comment: These constants are not just magic numbers, they are magic numbers without any meaning on their own. At the very least you would replace them with an enum. If the same compiled code needs to handle data from different sources, you’d have to make everything configurable.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hide the `int` ids in opaque objects/structs;

```
var id = level.id;
```

Here `id` is such a struct.

This way you can remove the `ById(int)` method and replace it with `ById(Id)` and it still lets you keep the cashed `Id`s for future use.

You can also create unique ID types for each reference type to ensure type safety (so you can't do `NodeReference.ById(level.id)`).

Comment: I did something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2930351/3312

Comment: I like this because it's doesn't significantly complicate the API.

Comment: Figured this would be fairly obvious. Good answer by me. If the developer doesn't want to do it then they can leave.

Comment: I'm aware OP mistakenly asked about constants instead of literals so you're answering the question to the letter; but this answer doesn't really address the _intended_ question on how to avoid developers using literals. Anything can be hardcoded, including an object/struct with its property values. A developer who thinks hardcoding an `int` is the way to go, is probably just going to hardcode your object/struct as well.

Comment: @Flater But in C# (and many OOP languages) you can prevent outside code from constructing an `id` struct and restrict construction to only the class the ID pertains to.

Comment: @ratchetfreak This doesn't change the fact that someone outside of that class is deciding what ID value they want to use, and they can just hardcode it there. You're passing the buck, but unless those developers simply don't develop the consuming code, they can just do the same there.

Comment: code review will prevent that kind of change. And being able to work around is fine as long as the work-around is more cumbersome than the idiomatic way you intend to be used.

Answer (score 23):

Provide a better API:

```
var node = NodeReference.byName("Reporting", "Default", "Patient", _patientGuid.ToString());
```

Or provide utility functions to fetch important nodes

```
var node = NodeReference.byName( theDefaultPatientNode(), _patientGuid.ToString() );
```

Or have the various nodes in an enum, and do something like:

```
var node = NodeReference.byCategory( REPORT_PATIENT, _patientGuid.ToString() );
```

You aren't going to be able to sell writing 4 lines of code to do something this simple. They are trying to use ids because its too hard to fetch the relevant object otherwise. So make it easier!

Comment: I've thought about this actually. The problem with this is that there's 2-5 different ways of creating each reference type. `ById` is the simplest, but every other method requires a separate reference. To provide all methods for generating references in one function call would require on the order of a hundred different overloads. The enum method might work, but that would be up to the client application developer to write.

Comment: @p.s.w.g, that just reinforces my impression: it's far too difficult to get these nodes and that's why they are falling back to ids. I think you need to find a way to make it easier to access the nodes rather then slapping their hands for it with ids.

Comment: You're right. I've been tossing around the idea of a URI style syntax for creating references like `NodeReference.ByUri("//Reporting/Default/Patient/#{_patientGuid}")`. I guess I'll have to formalize the syntax and write a parser in the next release.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Why would you want to use a single string? The solution given by Winston (a method with several parameters) is much better and simpler (no need for a parser).

Comment: @svick like I said, `ByName` is just one way of getting a `NodeReference`, there are several more. There are also a many ways of creating a `LevelReference`, `AreaReference`, and `ApplicationReference`. I'd have to provide overloads for each method of creating a complete reference chain. With the URI, the developer can do `"//Reporting/Default/Patient/#{...}"` or `"//Reporting/Default/rank:5/parent:jsmith/*"` or whatever their application demands.

Comment: @p.s.w.g In that case, you might consider LINQ-like solution. When choosing between XPath (which you're closely emulating) and LINQ to XML, I think the latter almost always wins. And your situation seems to be very similar.

Comment: @svick Interesting... could you elaborate?

Comment: @p.s.w.g I don't fully understand what your strings are supposed to do, but I meant something like `NodeReference.ByName("Reporting").ByName("Default").Rank(5).Parent("jsmith")`. The biggest advantages of this approach are better type-safety, “typo-safety” and support for IntelliSense.

Comment: @svick Ah right. One of the main reasons I haven't gone further with this is that I was trying to decide between the reference uri system or some kind of fluent `ReferenceBuilder` API like you suggest. I think I still favor the uri system ATM because it's easier to save that in the 'app.config' and remove all magic constants from the code (which will probably end up being my next battle).

Answer (score 9):

Code like

```
var level = LevelReference.ById(20);
```

should never pass a code review, because it contains [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants). That alone should be reason enough to ban such practices.

And if they try to work around it by creating named constants, the reviewer should ask the author for where he got the guarantee that the number is correct for all deployments.

Comment: var app = ApplicationReference.ByName("Reporting");
var area = AreaReference.ByName(app, "Default");
var level = LevelReference.ByName(area, "Patient"); also contain magic numbers

Comment: @PieterB: No, those lines contain string constants whose significance should be immediately apparent to any developer working on the project. The numeric constant `20` does not have such significance. With the strings, if any of the values must change, you can do that with a fairly trivial search/replace, but that does not work for the numeric constant.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, those IDs are the primary keys (identity column) in the database. In this case, a workaround would be not to forbid or track the constants in code, but simply randomize those keys in the deployment script.

Since IDs are not guaranteed to stay the same in the test data, the only solution for the developers would be to move to something more reliable - in your case, names.

Comment: I like this answer, but it is devious and it seems like it could create more work than it's worth during testing.

Answer (score 5):

Smack their hand in code review.

That said, is there a real difference between `LevelReference.ById()` and `LevelReference.ByName()`? In your example you are using hard coded values in both.

In one code base I've worked on we handled a similar situation by predefining the "hard coded" values that are set up with our database setup script and have an enumeration that maps an enumerated value to the database value.

Comment: ID's are environment specific. Names are application specific (different applications use this service). Yes both use constants, but the name is a much better choice since it's environment-independent.

Comment: Right. But there's no way for the compiler to know the difference between which hard coded constant is good and which hard coded constant is bad.

Comment: I was thinking about something kind of like a custom FxCop rule.

Comment: A custom rule that matched `Thing.ById(::digit::+)` would just irritate a lazy developer and have them write `thing_id = 4` on the line above it.

Answer (score 4):

It appears you are trying to find a technical solution to a social problem.  You should call it out in code reviews.  Do something in your testing/staging environment to ensure that node numbers will *never* match a clean dev environment - perhaps insert a random number of garbage rows on each install - and throw it back to the dev as broken.

If people insist on trying to work around this, you let them go.

Comment: You're correct that at the core this is a social problem, best fixed with code reviews. Sadly, we don't have the resources to review every check-in. I could periodically rebuild the tables in the stage / dev environment so that the ID's get jumbled up. Kind of like shaking a tree to see what falls out.

Answer (score 3):

**Doctor!  Doctor!  It hurts when I do this!**

Developers are misusing your API because you've provided it to them.  If you think `LevelReference.ById()` isn't good to use, you shouldn't provide it.  If you take it away, they'll stop using it :-)

Since we're talking about C#, you can also mark `ById()` as `[Obsolete]` and they'll at least get a deprecation warning.  For those who compile with all-warnings-are-errors, that's fatal.

Comment: There are valid use cases for `ById` -- e.g. caching it from the result of one query and then using it in subsequent queries to avoid the cost of solving the more indirect references. I'd like to not `[Obsolete]` the method entirely, just raise the flag when they use constants.

Comment: But code reviews! Automated builds, with lots of tests! (Seriously, this is the answer I voted for.)

Answer (score 0):

Supply an accessor object with getters returning ById(1), ById(2) etc. Then replace all calls to ById(constant) with calls to these getters. Obviously use sensible names for the getters.

Now if your code is *really* messed up and you used ById(20) to access different data from different sources then you need a second accessor and need to be *very* careful what to replace each ById call with.

But now you can put the accessors together with your documentation of your ids (I hope it’s all documented) so if ids change, you have one place to change.

If you for example access different versions of the same database at runtime, with different ids, you can create two accessor objects, one for each database version with different ids. This is the point where the hard coded constants would kill you.